# (unknown) user is always logged in my centos linux machine

Tags: linux, centos

I was going through logged in user in to my system using who command what i found is very surprising a user named unknown is logged in

Result of command who :

```
 myuser    pts/1        Aug  6 20:27 (localhost)
 (unknown) :0          Aug  5 16:25 (:0) 
 myuser    pts/0        Aug  6 00:48 (localhost.localdomain)
```

But when i tried running w it results different:

```
20:46:53 up 1 day, 23:11,  3 users,  load average: 1.00, 1.01, 1.05
USER     TTY      FROM             LOGIN@   IDLE   JCPU   PCPU WHAT
myuser    pts/1    localhost        20:27    5.00s  0.20s  0.03s w
myuser    pts/0    localhost.locald 00:48   19:57m  0.08s  1.71s python2 -m guake.main
```

I am neither able to find any user on my machine named unknown. On trying sudo su unknown/"(unknown)"

I tried running last it shows unknown user still logged in

```
myuser    pts/1        localhost        Thu Aug  6 20:27   still logged in
myuser    pts/2        :pts/1:S.0       Thu Aug  6 20:15 - 20:16  (00:00)
myuser    pts/1        localhost        Thu Aug  6 20:03 - 20:18  (00:15)
myuser    pts/2        :pts/1:S.0       Thu Aug  6 19:49 - 19:49  (00:00)
myuser    pts/1        localhost        Thu Aug  6 19:47 - 19:49  (00:02)
myuser    pts/1        localhost        Thu Aug  6 19:37 - 19:46  (00:09)
myuser    pts/1        localhost        Thu Aug  6 19:33 - 19:37  (00:03)
myuser    pts/1        :9               Thu Aug  6 19:32 - 19:33  (00:00)
myuser    pts/1        localhost        Thu Aug  6 19:26 - 19:32  (00:05)
myuser    pts/2        :pts/1:S.0       Thu Aug  6 19:22 - 19:22  (00:00)
myuser    pts/1        localhost        Thu Aug  6 19:22 - 19:22  (00:00)
myuser    pts/2        :pts/1:S.0       Thu Aug  6 19:15 - 19:16  (00:00)
myuser    pts/1        localhost        Thu Aug  6 19:15 - 19:16  (00:00)
myuser    pts/2        :pts/1:S.0       Thu Aug  6 19:13 - 19:13  (00:00)
myuser    pts/1        localhost        Thu Aug  6 19:13 - 19:13  (00:00)
myuser    pts/2        :pts/1:S.0       Thu Aug  6 19:12 - 19:13  (00:00)
myuser    pts/2        :pts/1:S.0       Thu Aug  6 19:11 - 19:11  (00:00)
myuser    pts/2        :pts/1:S.0       Thu Aug  6 19:10 - 19:10  (00:00)
myuser    pts/1        localhost        Thu Aug  6 18:37 - 19:13  (00:35)
myuser    pts/1        localhost        Thu Aug  6 18:17 - 18:21  (00:03)
myuser    pts/1        localhost        Thu Aug  6 18:09 - 18:13  (00:03)
myuser    pts/0        localhost.locald Thu Aug  6 00:48   still logged in
myuser    pts/0        localhost.locald Thu Aug  6 00:34 - 00:48  (00:14)
myuser    pts/1        :9               Wed Aug  5 23:01 - 23:01  (00:00)
myuser    pts/0        localhost.locald Wed Aug  5 22:00 - 00:34  (02:34)
myuser    pts/0        localhost        Wed Aug  5 21:06 - 21:06  (00:00)
myuser    pts/0        localhost        Wed Aug  5 20:57 - 20:59  (00:01)
myuser    pts/0        localhost        Wed Aug  5 20:56 - 20:56  (00:00)
myuser    pts/0        localhost        Wed Aug  5 20:56 - 20:56  (00:00)
myuser    pts/0        :9               Wed Aug  5 20:55 - 20:56  (00:00)
myuser    pts/4        localhost        Wed Aug  5 20:14 - 20:55  (00:40)
myuser    pts/4        localhost        Wed Aug  5 20:11 - 20:12  (00:00)
myuser    pts/5        localhost        Wed Aug  5 19:52 - 19:56  (00:04)
myuser    pts/4        localhost        Wed Aug  5 19:29 - 19:31  (00:02)
myuser    pts/2        localhost        Wed Aug  5 18:42 - 19:32  (00:49)
myuser    pts/2        localhost        Wed Aug  5 18:42 - 18:42  (00:00)
myuser    pts/3        :9               Wed Aug  5 18:38 - 18:42  (00:04)
myuser    pts/3        localhost        Wed Aug  5 16:28 - 16:28  (00:00)
myuser    pts/2        :9               Wed Aug  5 16:26 - 16:28  (00:02)
(unknown :0           :0               Wed Aug  5 16:25   still logged in
```

Any idea how ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I faced a similar problem some time ago on a Fedora host. 
In my case, i found it was the X system that created a wrong entry in /var/run/utmp.

Here the [link](http://forums.fedoraforum.org/showthread.php?t=283842) to the page.

Maybe you are not using Fedora but I suggest to try disable X and check if you still have an (unknown) user logged in.

Hope this helps.

Comment: yes it works this is basically because of gdm creating wrong entry in /var/run/utmp but i need to run vnc server so i need to go with this :)

Answer (score 2):

I saw this appearing in a Fedora installation in the past, when I launched the X from a tty (not in init 5)
In red hat, there is a bug open related to this problem [here](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=760834) (but maybe you are not even running a red hat based distro)

Take a look on it, there are some possible explanations, but depends on what you are running in your box

Comment: i am running centos 7 with gnome , as bug says it might be gdm writing something wrong on /var/run/utmp